# dict value in struct is ignored for Bool

Tags: swift

*now with a happy, short **Minimum Viable Example**  at the bottom*

I am seeing this weird behavior .. I am trying to set  a time series entry with location to true:

```
struct TimeSeriesEntry: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let date: Date
    let apps: [String:Double]
    let locations: [String:Bool]

    func changeApp(app: String, value: Double) -> TimeSeriesEntry {
        var apps = self.apps
        apps[app] = value

        return TimeSeriesEntry(id: self.id, uid: self.uid, date: self.date, apps: apps, locations: self.locations)
    }
}
```

There are no extensions to this code. That is `TimeSeriesEntry` in its entirety.

I am evaluating this in the debugger because for some reason it always is set *false*, but I do the assignment hard coded to *true* in my code. It works the same in the debugger:

#### debugger Evaluation

```
TimeSeriesEntry(id: String(describing: UUID()), uid: DBIFirebase.uid, 
    date: data.date.round(to: TimeSeries.defaults.interval, 
    TimeSeries.defaults.intervalComponent), apps:[:], locations: 
    [data.id:true])
.locations["c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"]
```

#### result

```
... = (Bool?) false
```

Elsewhere, when I am assigning `apps`, the Doubles are working just fine. I'm a bit stuck as to why this is happening.

### addendums

the actual assignment is happening in this function, and in this branch of the code it is the section in the function for locations, not apps:

```
func timeSeriesData (appData: AppData? = nil, locationData: LocationData? = nil) -> TimeSeriesEntry? {
    if let data = appData {
        return TimeSeriesEntry(id: String(describing: UUID()), uid: DBIFirebase.uid, date: data.date.round(to: TimeSeries.defaults.interval, TimeSeries.defaults.intervalComponent), apps: [data.id:data.metric], locations:[:])
    } else {
        guard let data = locationData else {
            return nil
        }
        return TimeSeriesEntry(id: String(describing: UUID()), uid: DBIFirebase.uid, date: data.date.round(to: TimeSeries.defaults.interval, TimeSeries.defaults.intervalComponent), apps:[:], locations: [data.id:true])
    }
}
```

*to make it a complete standalone mve:*

```
import Foundation

struct TimeSeriesEntry: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let date: Date
    let apps: [String:Double]
    let locations: [String:Bool]

    func changeApp(app: String, value: Double) -> TimeSeriesEntry {
        var apps = self.apps
        apps[app] = value

        return TimeSeriesEntry(id: self.id, uid: self.uid, date: self.date, apps: apps, locations: self.locations)
    }
}

struct LocationData: Codable, Equatable {
    //    let name: String
    let id: String
    let date: Date
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}

func timeSeriesData (locationData: LocationData) -> TimeSeriesEntry? {
    return TimeSeriesEntry(id: String(describing: UUID()), uid: "DBIFirebase.uid", date: locationData.date, apps:[:], locations: [locationData.id:true])
}

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

let locationData = LocationData(
    id: "c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a",
    date: df.date(from: "2017-08-28 00:00:01Z")!,
    latitude: 67.1404,
    longitude: -151.4804)

let timeSeriesEntry = timeSeriesData(locationData: locationData)
```

in repl, locations will contain 1 entry with the correct id but the bool set *false*:

```
 39. let timeSeriesEntry = timeSeriesData(locationData: locationData)

df: DateFormatter = {
  Foundation.Formatter = {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = NSDateFormatter
    }
  }
}
locationData: LocationData = {
  id = "c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"
  date = 2017-08-28 00:00:01 UTC
  latitude = 67.1404
  longitude = -151.4804
}
timeSeriesEntry: TimeSeriesEntry? = some {
  id = "C836C671-B266-4CA1-9A80-841E3329C6C8"
  uid = "DBIFirebase.uid"
  date = 2017-08-28 00:00:01 UTC
  apps = 0 key/value pairs
  locations = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      key = "c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"
      value = false
    }
  }
}
```

edit: okay, now Im confused.. playing with it a bit more in the repl, I see:

```
 42> timeSeriesEntry!.locations["c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"]
$R1: Bool? = true
 43> timeSeriesEntry!
$R2: TimeSeriesEntry = {
  id = "C836C671-B266-4CA1-9A80-841E3329C6C8"
  uid = "DBIFirebase.uid"
  date = 2017-08-28 00:00:01 UTC
  apps = 0 key/value pairs
  locations = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      key = "c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"
      value = false
    }
  }
}
 44> timeSeriesEntry!.locations
$R3: [String : Bool] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "c72b2cc2-897e-4621-8fba-452cf43afa0a"
    value = false
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you hard code the value ?

Comment: @MartinR all of the code necessary to run this in the repl is now in the description. I've tested it.

Comment: That is very strange. I can reproduce the problem, but cannot explain it. It happens only in the REPL. `timeSeriesEntry!.locations` shows the value as `false`, but `print(timeSeriesEntry!.locations)` prints the correct value `true`.

Comment: It suffices to enter `let dict = ["key" : true]` in the REPL to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Martin R: what do you test in REPL and what result do you get ? I tested 
let dict = ["key" : true]
let xTest = dict["key"]!
print(dict["key"]!)
and get true in both results.

Comment: @claude31: Yes, printing the dictionary or accessing its values works as expected. But try `let dict = ["key" : true]` and then just enter `dict` on the next line.

Comment: I get ["key": true] ; what do you get ?

Comment: @claude31: As strangely as it sounds, it prints `["key" : false]` in my Swift 4.2.1 REPL. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Martin R: I'm using Xcode 10.1ß3

Comment: @MartinR: So that should be Swift 4.1. Which means the bug has probably be introduced in 4.2. Worth a bug report.

Comment: @claude31: Already done: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9697 :)